# Move the checkboxes to the left in phpmyadmin

Tags: phpmyadmin

I have a simple issue that I am unable to resolve. In phpmyadmin, I'd like the checkboxes from the "Delete, Copy, Edit" column to be on the left instead of the right.

Example of what I have with the checkboxes on the right: 
[image]

Example of what I need with the the checkboxes on the right:

[image]

I looked through all the options and tried to drag the column but it didn't work. Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The configuration directive $cfg['RowActionLinks'] is the one you need to set to 'left' :
https://docs.phpmyadmin.net/en/latest/config.html#cfg_RowActionLinks

Comment: Thanks a lot! I unfortunately don't have access to my phpmyadmin directory so I can't change it. Hope this will help someone in the future though.

Comment: Depending on your phpMyAdmin installation, this setting is also changeable per user (MySQL user), via Settings > Main panel > Browse mode > Where to show the table row links